# My Computer ran out of RAM in startup

Tags: windows-10, memory, freeze

My Windows ran out of RAM every time it's startup. I have Rainmeter on my desktop. I add RAM Meter on the desktop. Everytime my computer startup, I can see on the RAM meter that my RAM starting to drain out until 7 mb RAM left. After that, my PC freeze. So I just need to force shut down my PC and turn on again. This problem appears sometimes, not everytime it's startup.
I tried to open Task Manager but it wasn't fast yet to open while my RAM ranning out

OS : Windows 10
RAM : 4gb DDR3

Is there any solution? Or how can I see my RAM history Usage?

Feel free to ask something

Comment: How much RAM is installed, in the first place?

Comment: @Kinnectus 4gb RAM

Comment: What Type of RAM, What version of windows are you running?

Comment: Open `Task Manager` to see what is hogging your memory.

Comment: @DavidGolding DDR3

Comment: I wasn't fast to open Task Manager while my RAM ranning out @Kinnectus

Comment: Do you have custom scripts or tasks that are set to run at startup?

Comment: @marijnr No, or maybe it caused by startup programs?

Comment: Perform a clean boot of Windows (not a re-install, a mode where it only starts with system services and drivers).

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this issue several times while fixing up older systems. What you want to try and do is have a successful start up to where you can access the task manager. From there you can see exactly what is using the RAM, and how much.

At this point we already know that something (or several things) is affecting the startup and using up your computers resources. In my experience applications like Rain meter, or possibly others you have installed, will use more of those resources.

So, if you can get into the task manager and look under the startup tab, you will see which applications launch on system startup and the type of impact those have on performance. If it has a high impact, this tells you that it is using more resources.

What you can do here is disable some of these applications from launching on startup, which in most cases will fix the issue of running out of RAM.

Another option would be to upgrade the RAM to, let's say, 8GB, which could also solve the issue since you're increasing the computer resources available.